# Swift - is there a short hand property like Objective-C?

Tags: swift

I am trying to see if there is a short-hand way to write the following using Swift.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor* circleColor
```

I have read through the documentation and I can't seem to find a way to shorten properties in general without having to writing both the setters and/or getters.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by shorthand, but the exact equivalent of your code in Swift would be: `var circleColor:UIColor!`. No need for getters/setters

Comment: @JackWu: Nooo! Stop thinking in terms of C/C++. Use `UIColor?` instead because `UIColor!` defeats the safety and much of the purpose of optionals. Yes, then the code has to be written differently, but that's a good thing.

Comment: @AlvinThompson I hate the implicitly unwrapped `!`, but if you are going for ObjC Swift interop thats the way to go. Its basically the reason the `!` variable type exists anyways

Comment: @JackWu: True. If you're simply porting code "line by line" you can get going with the fewest edits (and the least thinking) that way. But I think the real reason they have `!` is that optionals can be a hard concept for developers not used to it to grok, and they clearly designed the language to attract as many devels as possible in the short term so it gains traction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equivalent of that in Swift would be this:

```
var circleColor:UIColor
```

which is actually a good deal shorter than the ObjC version. Swift somewhat merges the concepts of properties and instance variables.

If you need 'nil' to be a possible value for circleColor, then use 'UIColor?' instead of 'UIColor'.

Comment: So, does it mean that Swift doesn't have private ivars (like Python)?

Comment: @IgorKhomenko Yes, currently it doesn't, but Apple has confirmed that Swift will have private vars soon.

Comment: ObjC also didn't have private vars until a while after OSX was released (more than a decade after ObjC was released and NeXT shipped using it)

Comment: @Catfish_Man What about the attributes? nonatomic, strong etc. Should I be worry about those?

Comment: Swift does not (currently) have any language level concurrency features like atomic or @synchronized. Use NSLock or dispatch_sync/dispatch_async for thread-safety instead.

Comment: weak and strong are supported just fine in Swift though, just 'weak var foo:SomeClass?' and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this answer to raise the visibility of @JackWu's comment - the way this should be done is:

```
var circleColor: UIColor!
```

The implicitly-unwrapped version is the recommended way and more closely represents how object properties work in Obj-C right now (i.e. the fact that they begin life as nil once declared).

Comment: "Should" is very subjective. To all readers: look at the cases for and against `!` and `?` presented on this page and make your own decision!

Comment: I don't view ! as a "recommendation" so much as it's a tools limitation. ObjC doesn't expose enough information to decide between Optional and non-Optional, so the importer compromises for imported APIs.

Comment: those are fair comments for sure, everybody should be aware of and informed about the cases for-and-against `?` -vs- `!` - I added 'recommended' because in this context (re: the Swift equivalent of a 'property') it was described this way in WWDC sessions, and because almost every instance I've seen of Swift versions of the Cocoa APIs shows them declaring properties this way (e.g. UIViewController is declared with its properties as so -->> `var view: UIView!; var nibName: String! { get }; var nibBundle: NSBundle! { get };` etc.)